# flatten pdf tool

Tags: pdf

I need a way to flatten PDFs, treating them as images. I frequently use LibreOffice Draw, as it is the perfect tool for many tasks. However, it has a frustrating bug when it comes to Hebrew text (I'm Israeli); it struggles to handle it properly.

My current workaround is to open the file with GIMP, export it immediately, and then open it with Draw.

My goal is to write a script that can export the PDF into individual PNG pages and then merge them back together. So far, I haven't come across any tools that can perform these actions directly from the terminal.

Ideally, if there is a standalone tool capable of accomplishing this task, it would be perfect for my needs.

I am using Fedora 38.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combination from `pdftoppm` and `convert` from `ImageMagick`.

To convert from `pdf` to `png` you can use command:

```
pdftoppm input.pdf output -png
```

this will produce `png` files like `output-1.png`, `output-2.png` and so on.

To recreate `pdf` from `png's` you can use command:

```
convert output-*.png flat_output.pdf
```